# HttpWebRequest descendant

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, httpwebrequest, webclient

I'm trying to use instead of usual `HttpWebRequest`

```
// get a login page
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.facebook.com/");
```

my configured class `FacebookHttpWebRequest`, that look like this:

```
// get a login page
FacebookHttpWebRequest req = (FacebookHttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.facebook.com/");
```

Here is configured class implementation

```
class FacebookHttpWebRequest : HttpWebRequest
    {
        public FacebookHttpWebRequest() : base()
        {
            this.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1";
            this.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";            
        }
    }
```

but there is a error raised Error

> 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' does not contain a constructor that
>   takes 0 arguments

And it really requires two arguments: `serializationInfo` and `streamingContext`.

So how can I make my own `HttpWebRequest` descendant? I know I can use special method that will configure usual `HttpWebRequest`, but it will be more elegantly to have special class for that.

Comment: *Why* would you want to do that? When in doubt, you should favor composition over inheritance, i.e., create a class with `HttpWebRequest` as a field.

Comment: I want to have all-time configured HttpWebRequest instance instead of configuring it each time

Comment: Then create a *function* that creates instances and returns configured ones. Inheritance is overkill in this scenario.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari Please see my question update. It more interested to setup separate class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need inheritance for this. Just wrap the creation login in your own factory:

```
static class FacebookWebRequestFactory {
  public static HttpWebRequest Create() {
    var req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.facebook.com/");
    req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:8.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/8.0.1";
    req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";            
    return req;
  }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
var req = FacebookWebRequestFactory.Create();
```